# Try to scrape image from image url (using python urllib ) but get html instead

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib, scrape

I've tried to get the image from the following url.

> http://upic.me/i/fj/the_wonderful_mist_once_again_01.jpg

I can do right-click and save-as but when I tried to use urlretrieve like

```
import urllib
img_url = 'http://upic.me/i/fj/the_wonderful_mist_once_again_01.jpg'
urllib.urlretrieve( img_url, 'cover.jpg')
```

I found that it is html instead of .jpg image but I don't know why.
Could you please tell me why does my method not work? Are there any option that can mimic right-click save-as method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), if you havn't installed yet, [`pip install requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/)

Because this `img_url` was redirected by the server to another html page ( that was the html page you just downloaded) if you didn't provide a `referer` header.

So the following code first find the redirect url, and add it to the HTTP Referer header.

```
import requests
img_url = 'http://upic.me/i/fj/the_wonderful_mist_once_again_01.jpg'

r = requests.get(img_url, allow_redirects=False)   #  stop redirect 302 , capture redirects url

headers = {}
headers['Referer'] = r.headers['location']    # add this url to referer 'http://upic.me/show/55132055'

r = requests.get(img_url, headers=headers)
filename = img_url.split('/')[-1]             # find the file name in `img_url`
with open(filename, 'wb') as fh:             # use 'wb' to write in binary mode
    fh.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks, it does really work!  Very Thanks for clear explanation.

A senior told me to change 'http' to 'https' and it works also. Unfortunately, I have no chance to ask him for details.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
import urllib2

image = urllib2.urlopen('http://upic.me/i/fj/the_wonderful_mist_once_again_01.jpg').read()
f = open('some_name.jpg','w')
f.write(image)
f.close()
```

Comment: It doesn't work neither. The image is broken but if I save it as html, it's readable and it is actually html.