# Try to download image from image url, but get html instead

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2

similar to [Try to scrape image from image url (using python urllib ) but get html instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433699/try-to-scrape-image-from-image-url-using-python-urllib-but-get-html-instead) , but the solution does not work for me.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

img_url='http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/79/7041933-beautiful-backgrounds-wallpaper.jpg'

r = requests.get(img_url, allow_redirects=False)

headers = {}
headers['Referer'] = r.headers['location']

r = requests.get(img_url, headers=headers)
with open('7041933-beautiful-backgrounds-wallpaper.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)
```

the downloaded file is still a html page, not an image.

Comment: because this web site has redirection mechanism mean if you will hit resource directly it will redirect you to the HTML page. so from code when u request this image resource server redirect to html page and then we get this html file. not image file.

Comment: so there is no solution for this web site?

Comment: Usually the solution is to replicate what your browser does.  So fire up chrome, open the developer tools, switch to the network tab. Then load the page that hosts that image.  What usually happens is there is some sort of cookie (or other HTTP artefact) created on the HTML page, that gets sent with the request for your image.  So look at the request that the browser makes for the image, and see what headers and cookies are sent with it. Then look through the rest of the traffic to see where they came from.

Comment: you want to save the image file locally?

Comment: @DeepakSharma , yup.

Comment: try  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286352/how-to-save-an-image-locally-using-python-whose-url-address-i-already-know#answer-8286449

you may get same prob here also but I just want you to make it sure either its working on this one is also failed.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, using urllib.urlretrieve still gets a html page, not an image.

Comment: @GregHNZ, it will open a new tab when I click the image, then the tool box of chrome is gone in the new tab. I can not capture any network resource...

Comment: Can you open the dev tools in the new window, then hit refresh?

Comment: @GregHNZ, the network resource is still the `img_url`, but I can see some cookies. one is PHPSeedID (only in the session) and the other one is _ga (expire time is 2018 yr). Do I need to specify the cookie in the request header?

Comment: You probably need to code a request to the html page,  parse the cookies etc from the response, and add them to your request for the image.

Comment: @GregHNZ, I put both cookies in the request, but still got a html page.

Comment: Hi guys, I found a solution for this. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your referrer was not being set correctly. I have hard coded the referrer and it works fine

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

img_url='http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/79/7041933-beautiful-backgrounds-wallpaper.jpg'

r = requests.get(img_url, allow_redirects=False)

headers = {}
headers['Referer'] = 'http://7-themes.com/7041933-beautiful-backgrounds-wallpaper.html'

r = requests.get(img_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
with open('7041933-beautiful-backgrounds-wallpaper.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)
```

Comment: yup. I just found my root cause is the `refer` field, but it's not necessary to make two http request.

Answer (score 0):

I found a root cause in my code is that refer field in the header is still a html, not image.

So I change the refer field to the `img_url`, and this works.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib
import requests

img_url='http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/79/7041933-beautiful-backgrounds-wallpaper.jpg'

headers = {}
headers['Referer'] = img_url

r = requests.get(img_url, headers=headers)

with open('7041933-beautiful-backgrounds-wallpaper.jpg', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(r.content)
```